# Text vertically & horizontally aligned on image on responsive Wordpress page

Tags: html, css, wordpress

[Here's the page upon which I'm working.](http://www.optimumproductions.com/portfolio_2/)

I'm using Shortcodes Ultimate to get the columns, and it's responsive. Now I'm trying to get a text hover with background over the images, preferably without JS for now. I can get it to hover perfectly if it's given defined height and width, but then that's not responsive.

On CodePen, it shows the title going all the way across the page, but the Shortcodes Ultimate columns eliminate that. But it probably isn't best design, either.

I've followed about 20 different tutorials to get where I am, but am stuck now.

[CodePen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/jbPjjZ)

HTML:

```
<div id="portfolio_hover_wrapper">
  <a href="#" class="wistia-popover">
    <img src="https://embed-ssl.wistia.com/deliveries/b9d3c0914d895ac2fb274c0c8798ad66f6e5d4f0.jpg?image_crop_resized=640x360" alt="" class="hover" />
    <span class="portfolio-hover-text"><span>ADO Rowing</span>
  </a>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#portfolio_hover_wrapper {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  text-align: center;
}

#portfolio_hover_wrapper a {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;  
  position: relative;
}


span.portfolio-hover-text {
  background: rgba(27,187,230,0.8);
  color: white;
  display: table;
  font-size: 3em;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 500ms;
  -moz-transition: opacity 500ms;
  -o-transition: opacity 500ms;
  transition: opacity 500ms;
}



#portfolio_hover_wrapper a:hover span.portfolio-hover-text {
    opacity: 1;
}

span.portfolio-hover-text span {
  display: table-cell;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Comment: You want that banner overlaying the image and in the center of the image correct? On mousover correct? That could be done completely in CSS if that works for you

Comment: Does this codepen work for you? if so I'll make it into an answer and explain it. http://codepen.io/XanderLuciano/pen/BoNXJr

Comment: Except for the bottom.

http://imgur.com/aXN7Eva

Comment: Alright give me a little and I'll get you a better working example. It looks like your font size ended up a little bit differently than mine. All you have to do is increase the padding on the bottom for that though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<s>If I understand what you want try using `top: 50%; transform: translateY(-50%);` in `.portfolio-hover-text`.</s>

My bad I misunderstood your question, try adding the following:

```
span.portfolio-hover-text {
    background: rgba(27,187,230,0.8);
    color: white;
    display: block;
    font-size: 3em;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 500ms;
    -moz-transition: opacity 500ms;
    -o-transition: opacity 500ms;
    transition: opacity 500ms;
}
span.portfolio-hover-text span{
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

Comment: Really close. I've updated [the page](http://www.optimumproductions.com/portfolio_2/) with it; the color BG now only covers the text and not the whole image, but it IS centered vertically.

Comment: Hmm what browser are you using? It seems fine to me.

Comment: On a Mac.

Chrome & Safari both show the same, where the BG only covers the text area.

Firefox, OTOH, shows the color correctly, but all the columns are effed up & no longer responsive. Perhaps a Shortcode Ultimate issue? But I'm pretty sure I checked it before going down this overlay hover route and it was responsive.

Comment: Did the trick in Chrome.

Firefox has that alignment issue with the boxes.

IE 11 has box problems, and also aligns the text incorrectly.

Safari shows the boxes correctly, but aligns the text to the right.

Comment: Adding `Left:50%` corrects IE but as it, like Firefox, has the incorrect box sizing it only appears to be positioned wrong. If we can fix the box sizing then this will work on all of them now.

Comment: Add `display:block` to `.su-column-size-1-2`, and that should fix it!!

Comment: Unfortunately not, but adding in Shortcode's `[row]` tags does. Works in FF and Chrome now, but Safari still has the text awkwardly to the right and down a bit. I tried adding `left: 50%;` to both `span.portfolio-hover-text span` and `span.portfolio-hover-text` but neither one did anything.

`[row]` has the unfortunate side effect of creating padding in my vertical rows, however.

Comment: The website works in it's current state. Appologies, I can't test in Safari. But I do know safari requires a `-webkit` vendor prefix (as stated [here](http://caniuse.com/#feat=transforms2d)) which is probably why it appears to be slightly shifted - that's what the transform corrects.

Comment: webkit fixed it. Your solution was the most helpful and worked with what I already had. I can figure out row spacing separately. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In order to overlay text over an image I like to set the parent DIV to have the image as a background and child the text to it like such

```
<div class="box image1">
  <div class="overlay fade">
    <span class="text">ADO Rowing</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.box {
  width: 75%; /*To make it responsive*/
  height: 40em;/*Height should be fixed*/
  box-shadow: inset 0px 2px 7px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .6);/*just for looks*/
  margin: 5% auto 0 auto; /*Centers the div*/
  border-radius: 5px; /*just for looks*/
  overflow: hidden; /*Needed if our text overflows*/
}

.image1 {
  background: url(https://embed-ssl.wistia.com/deliveries/b9d3c0914d895ac2fb274c0c8798ad66f6e5d4f0.jpg?image_crop_resized=640x360);/*Image*/
  background-size: cover;/*Makes the background look responsive*/
  background-position:center;/*for looks*/
}
```

Now we need to style the overlay. More CSS

```
.overlay {
  background: rgba(33, 150, 243, .6);/*Overlay color*/
  text-align: center;
  padding: 1em 0 1em 0;/*adjust this if you want it cover the entire img*/
  height:25%;/*Change this to 100% for whole image*/
  opacity: 0;
  margin: 25% 0 0 0;/*Moves the banner down*/
  box-shadow: 0 2px 7px rgba(33, 150, 243, .4);
}
.text {
  font-family: Helvetica;
  font-weight: 900;
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, .85);
  font-size: 96px;
}
```

Padding will increase the div size and thus increase the color size, while margin will just space the div out without changing the size of the background, so I use margin to position and padding for sizing.

lastly we need to make some snappy animation on :hover

```
.fade {
  -webkit-transition: opacity .25s ease;
  -moz-transition: opacity .25s ease;
  -ms-transition: opacity .25s ease;
  transition: opacity .25s ease;
}

.box:hover .fade {
  opacity:1;
}
```

That will change the opacity from 0 to 1 on hover with a .25s tranisition. That should be about it, hope that helps. View the [CodePen Here](http://codepen.io/XanderLuciano/pen/BoNXJr)

Comment: Can it be done with the image not having to be referenced by CSS? If I want to add 8 different links to the page, this coding makes it so I'll have to have 8 different classes & put the 8 image links in the CSS, vs. just popping it on the Wordpress HTML.

Comment: You could instead define the background image with inline CSS or use an IMG html tag and position:absolute them over each other. Which do you prefer?

Comment: It's probably an even trade. The inline CSS is probably more elegant, but the Wistia embed/pop-up already gives the <a><img> hierarchy, so merely adding the class to the IMG would be probably easiest.

Comment: I appreciate your help and work on this. It definitely helped me learn more about CSS and how various elements work by taking what you did and playing with the elements. The other solution brought me closer to what I needed for now, but your solution definitely helps me learn a lot.

Comment: Glad I could help! and that's what stack overflow is all about, helping others solve problems and learn more about programming. I'm just trying to be as helpful as I can!